# Basic data model for a food tracker

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to data modeling and trying to develop a Django model for a simple food tracker.

What did you eat?

- Pancakes

Meal

- Breakfast

Ingredients

- Eggs
- Flour
- Milk

Allergens

- Eggs

When the user logged their Food, Meal, and Ingredients it would lookup to see if any of those ingredients are a known allergen. What would be the appropriate data model for this? My guess is below.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Meal(models.Model):      
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Food(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Allergen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an is_allergent boolean field to Ingrediant model.

Think of allergy as just an attribute of Ingrediant. it could be allergic or not.